# Having difficulty printing strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf, scanf

When I run the program, the second `printf()` prints `string2` with whatever was scanned into `string1` attached to the end.

e.g. `123` was scanned into `string1` then it prints: `Is before "12ab123"`.
as opposed to `12ab`.

Why not just `"12ab"`?

```
char string1[MAX_STR_LEN];
char string2[4]={'1','2','a','b'};
char five='5';
char abc[3]={'a','b','c'};
printf("Enter a string:");
scanf("%s", string1);
printf("Is before \"%s\":",string2);
```

Answer (score 4):

A string is a null terminated char array in C.

Change

```
char string2[4]={'1','2','a','b'};
```

to

```
char string2[5]={'1','2','a','b', '\0'};
```

(which is the same as `char string2[] = "12ab";`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate your array with `NULL character` as

`char string2[5]={'1','2','a','b','\0'};`

When you are doing the `scanf()`, `string1` is stored in next memory so it is printing `string2` with `string1`. It will print upto it gets `\0` so its [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 char string2[4]={'1','2','a','b'};
```

`string2` is not null-terminated. Using that *array* as an argument to `%s` format specifier invokes undefined behavior, as it runs past the allocated memory in search of the null-terminator.

You need to add the null-terminator yourself like

```
char string2[5]={'1','2','a','b','\0'};
```

to use `string2` as a *string*.

Also, alternatively, you can write

```
char string2[ ]= "12ab";
```

to allow the compiler to decide the size, which considers the space for (and adds) the null-terminator.

Same goes for `abc` also.

That said, you're *scanning* into `string1` and printing `string2`, which is certainly not wrong, but does not make much sense, either.

Comment: `char string2[ ]={'1','2','a','b'};` is not null terminated either.

Comment: @BlueMoon I seriously need to go to bed, it's been a long day. Thanks. See you tomorrow with a fresh mind:-)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the previous answers, the strings appear to be joined due to the order the variables are stored in the stack memory.  This won't always work the same on every processor architecture or compiler (optimiser settings can change this behaviour too).

Answer (score 0):

If the format specifier `%s` does not have the precision flag then the function outputs characters until it encounteres zero character `'\0'`

Character array `string2` is defined such a way that it does not have the terminating zero

```
char string2[4]={'1','2','a','b'};
```

So the function outputs characters beyond the array until it meets zero character.

You could use the precision flag that to specify explicitly how many characters you are going to output. For example

```
printf("Is before \"%4.4s\":",string2);
```

Or you could define the array that includes the terminating zero. For example

```
char string2[5] = { '1', '2', 'a', 'b', '\0' };
```

Take into account that in this case the size of the array if it is specified shall be equal at least to 5 ( though the size can be greater than 5; in this case other characters that do not have initializers will be zero-initialized)

or simply

```
char string2[] = { "12ab" };
```

or without braces

```
char string2[] = "12ab";
```